# How to use MEF in Portable class library?

Tags: .net, mef, visual-studio-2012, portable-class-library, windows-store-apps

I have portable class library targeted to .NET 4.5 and Windows Store App. [According to MSDN this setting should offer MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx) but it does not. Namespace `System.ComponentModel.Composition` is not available (I even tried `System.Composition` but no luck). It is also not possible to use `Microsoft.Composition` NuGet package which works with Windows Store App.

The error when installing [NuGet version](https://nuget.org/packages/microsoft.composition) is:

> 'Microsoft.Composition 1.0.15' already installed. Could not install
>   package 'Microsoft.Composition 1.0.15'.
>
> You are trying to install this
>   package into a project that targets
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile7', but the package does not
>   contain any assembly references that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to manually add a reference to the binary from the package. I typically install the package to a platform-specific project (such as .NET Framework 4.5) then just manually reference from portable.

This will be fixed next version of NuGet (2.1) and we'll update the MEF package to coincide with it.