# Why doesn't new WSA Reflection API contain methods to get members with particular bindings?

Tags: .net, reflection, windows-store-apps, portable-class-library

Consider properties for example.

In old API I could call `Type.GetProperties(BindingFlgas.Static | BindingFlags.Public);`

But with `TypeInfo` I have either `DeclaredProperties` or `GetRuntimeProperties()` which return `PropertyInfo` instances.

But `PropertyInfo` does not contain `IsStatic`, `IsPublic` properties. To know this I first need to get Get or Set-method and check its properties.

It is said that new reflection API is more sound in architecture and performance ways.
But It's hard to believe in it. With example given above should I care about performance? May be I am missing something important in new approach?