# 'DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'FromOADate'

Tags: c#, mvvmcross

I want to convert a `double` value to `DateTime` and do some operation on it and again convert back `DateTime` value to `double`. But I am unable to call `DateTime.FromOADate()` and `DateTime.ToOADate()`; the methods don't exist.

Please help to resolve this.

Comment: Could you share some code? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Pilatus : In my mvvmcross xamarin project DateTime.FromOADate method not available but in API project DateTIme.FromOADate method available. I think in Web project DateTime support FromOADate  and ToOADate method but not support in mobile project.

Comment: What operation do you want to do?

Comment: @Nfear : I getting working hours in UTC in double type from API. So I just want convert double  value to DateTime and convert it into DateTime.ToLocalTime. And then convert DateTime value to double with local time to display.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the project that isn't able to call `ToOADate()` and `FromOADate()` because it is a `Portable Class Library (PCL)`.

The following [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518004/what-happened-to-toshortdatestring-in-net-portable-class-library) is about a different case but concludes that not all methods of `System.Datetime` are included.

Source: [What happened to .ToShortDateString in .NET Portable Class Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518004/what-happened-to-toshortdatestring-in-net-portable-class-library)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are using .NET Core Framework and you won't find these methods `DateTime.FromOADate()` and `DateTime.ToOADate()` because the OLE Automation Date exist only .NET Framework and .NET Core is cross platform Framework.

Comment: That's _exactly_ what I am doing which led me to this SO question... What puzzles me is that the `mscorelib` class in the coreclr repo seems to have this method: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/DateTime.cs#L735